# Defining a structured type in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures, types

I'm pretty sure there's a feature for that in the Matlab programming/script language, but I cannot find it. I guess I'm googling with the wrong words.

What I want to do is define a category of data items that will all share the same internal structure.

Like this:

```
I declare PERSON to be a type of structure consisting of:
   FIRST NAME  : text;
   LAST NAME : text;
   PHONE NUMBER : integer;;

Now I declare the following variables:

PERSON MIKE

PERSON JANE
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to create a **type**, then you need to define a custom class. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/user-defined-classes.html ---- note that such a class does not need to define methods, it can be purely a container for data, like a struct, but having a unique type, where you cannot add fields nilly-willy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you are searching for is **'Class'**

```
classdef Person
properties
    FirstName string % *
    LastName string 
    PhoneNumber double {mustBePositive,mustBeInRange(PhoneNumber,0000000000,99999999999)} % **
end
end
```

Some notes:

- the class must be in its own separate .m file which has to have the same name as the class itself
- you can set validation in the property section itself. It can be of type (*) or of more complex nature (**). You can read more here [Class Validation Docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/validate-property-values.html)
- Classes may or may not have methods, but still give them a look. Some methods like constructors, ... can be useful in any case.
- Be careful to not override already existent classes (the name is important)

To call the class just do:

```
 mike = person; %creates mike object
 mike.LastName='VeryImportantSurname' %assigns to its property
```

if you were to use constructors the code (incomplete for case handling, just an example) would be instead:

```
   classdef person
    properties
        FirstName string
        LastName string
        PhoneNumber double ...
            {mustBePositive,mustBeInRange(PhoneNumber,0000000000,99999999999)}
    end

    methods
        function obj=person(Fn,Ln,Pn)
            if nargin == 3
                obj.FirstName=Fn;
                obj.LastName=Ln;
                obj.PhoneNumber=Pn;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This would allow to call and assign directly:

```
mike=person('Mike','VeryImportantSurname',87345929) %creates mike object and assigns properties
```